# How can I call model through paperclip from batch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, batch-file

I am developing a batch that converts some symbols to html. The batch calls helper.rb and the helper actually changes the symbols to html.

When I fill in form from browser and submit it, the helper works. But When the batch calls the helper, it doesn't work. I am using paperclip to upload images and error is happening when Picture.find_by_id(20) is executed. Other models work well.

Could you tell me how to solve the issue?
In error log, looks like a bug. Is there anyone who could solve the same issue before? or Is it impossible?

### error log

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Comment: Is there anything else from the error log you can attach? Can you backtrack in your code and include what you think might be the relevant bits that produced the error?

Comment: another error log

/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/paperclip-5.0.0/lib/paperclip/callbacks.rb:12: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000c
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]